# AWS crc32 mismatch dynamo

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to request some entries from AWS DynamoDB from an App in Android Studio. I am getting a CRC32 mismatch for a scanResult. Does anyone know why this is happening. attaching snippet and stack trace below.

```
credentials = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            MapValidate.getContext(), // Context
            “FILLED_MY_ID_HERE", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
Region usEast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
dynamoDB.setRegion(usEast1);

HashMap<String,Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String,Condition>();

Condition condition1lat = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(user_lat));
scanFilter.put("DegLat", condition1lat);

ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("MY_TABLE_NAME")
            .withAttributesToGet("DegLat","DegLong","Latitude")
            .withScanFilter(scanFilter);

ScanResult result = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
```

I am getting the following exception as below:

```
04-28 19:34:03.729    4744-4793/com.google.sample I/AmazonHttpClient﹕ 
Unable to execute HTTP request: 
Client calculated crc32 checksum didn't match that calculated by server side
```

Comment: hey there, I am running into this same error just now when I updated to Android 7.0 Nougat. I am using the latest version of aws-dynamodb-sdk-2.3.0. I am only running into this error with my device running Android 7.0. Does anyone know if this is a bug in the aws sdk or something I can do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

CRC checksum errors may be caused by requesting compression in the request header.
If you have not already done this, please try the following with ClientConfiguration:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.withGzip(ClientConfiguration.DEFAULT_USE_GZIP /*false*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just resolved the issue. It is a problem with the sdk-2.2.0 . Upgraded to the latest version of 2.2.1 released a few days ago resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK actually does not support ClientConfiguration.DEFAULT_USE_GIP...  It does try to take this into consideration thought if you look at the HttpRequestFactory class https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/4de3a3146d66d9ab5684eb5e71d5a2cef9f4dec9/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/HttpRequestFactory.java If you have not explicitly set an Accept-Encoding, then the sdk will turn off compression by default.  If however you DID explicitly set it, you could be running in to compression problems.

Let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Thanks,
Weston

Comment: thank you for your response. In which part of the above fragment would I have to enable compression? I am unable to find the httprequestfactory.java file in my SDK. Also the query works for a subset of a table but does not work for the entire table

Comment: My apologies, the class I was referencing was indeed updated to fix this bug in 2.1.1.  Thanks for helping though, it's appreciated!