# Getting Crc32MismatchException when using dynamodb enhanced client

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0, dynamodb-enhanced-client

**Describe the bug**

We tried to getItem using DynamoDbEnhancedClient but we got Crc32MismatchException.

**Expected Behavior**

I should be able to getItem

**Current Behavior**

getting error:

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException: Expected
> 1657156166 as the Crc32 checksum but the actual calculated checksum
> was 3693931191    at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException$BuilderImpl.build(Crc32MismatchException.java:88)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.validateChecksum(Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.java:62)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.close(Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.java:50)
> at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(Unknown Source)    at
> software.amazon.awssdk.utils.FunctionalUtils.lambda$safeRunnable$5(FunctionalUtils.java:124)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.utils.FunctionalUtils.invokeSafely(FunctionalUtils.java:140)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.lambda$handle$4(JsonResponseHandler.java:94)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)   at
> software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:94)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:36)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonResponseHandler.handle(AwsJsonResponseHandler.java:44)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.lambda$handle$0(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDurationUnsafe(MetricUtils.java:64)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.handle(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:94)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$resultTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:287)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleSuccessResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:97)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:72)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:59)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:40)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:80)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:135)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:161)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:114)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:169)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:95)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClient.getItem(DefaultDynamoDbClient.java:3107)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.CommonOperation.execute(CommonOperation.java:114)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.TableOperation.executeOnPrimaryIndex(TableOperation.java:59)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(DefaultDynamoDbTable.java:139)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(DefaultDynamoDbTable.java:146)
> at
> software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.client.DefaultDynamoDbTable.getItem(DefaultDynamoDbTable.java:151)

**Reproduction Steps**

```
// https://www.http4k.org/api/org.http4k.client/-ok-http/
val httpClient: HttpHandler = OkHttp()
val awsHttpClient = AwsSdkClient(httpClient)
val dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient =
    DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .region(Region.of(environment.getAwsRegion()))
        .httpClient(awsHttpClient)
        .build()

val enhancedClient: DynamoDbEnhancedClient =
    DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient)
        .build()
val tableName = ...
val schema = ...
val table = enhancedClient.table(tableName, schema)
val key = ..
table.getItem(key)
```

**Possible Solution**

This has happened in aws-sdk-java, maybe it is missed in v2?
aws/aws-sdk-java#1018

**AWS Java SDK version used**

2.17.27

**JDK version used**

java 11

**Operating System and version**

Amazon Linux 2

Reported to [github/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3703)

[Related but not the same stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931897/aws-crc32-mismatch-dynamo)

Comment: Where did you find the logic to create your HTTP client? Can you share the AWS docs which reference it?

`val httpClient: HttpHandler = OkHttp()`
`val awsHttpClient = AwsSdkClient(httpClient)`

Comment: Good point, we are using defaultOkHttpClient() from http4k https://www.http4k.org/api/org.http4k.client/-ok-http/

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the AWS client directly (without using http4k-connect at all). I wonder if the problem is related to the link you shared to the other question (and that the default http client from http4k might not have compression enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Okhttp as client, you can add a custom header configuration: Accept-Encoding: gzip

You can do something like this in kotlin:

```
val httpClient: HttpHandler = OkHttp()
val awsHttpClient = AwsSdkClient(httpClient)
val dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient =
    DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .region(Region.of(environment.getAwsRegion()))
        .httpClient(awsHttpClient)
        .overrideConfiguration { o -> o.putHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip") }
        .build()

val enhancedClient: DynamoDbEnhancedClient =
    DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient)
        .build()
val tableName = ...
val schema = ...
val table = enhancedClient.table(tableName, schema)
val key = ..
table.getItem(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen others use OkHttp for their AWS clients before, and I believe that this HTTP client uses gzip compression by default. To change the configuration you would need to write a network interceptor as described [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/).

I suggest first building with the default HTTP client, which just requires you to remove 2 lines of code. That will allow you to understand if OkHTTP is in fact the issue.