# Getting Crc32MismatchException when using dynamodb enhanced client when we are using queryPaginator

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**Bug description**

We tried to queryPaginator using DynamoDbEnhancedClient but we got `software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException`.

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException: Expected 4178815326 as the Crc32 checksum but the actual calculated checksum was 3264908315

**Expected Behavior**
I should be able to queryPaginator results

**Current Behavior**

**Error logs:**

> "exception":"software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException: Expected 4178815326 as the Crc32 checksum but the actual calculated checksum was 3264908315\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.Crc32MismatchException$BuilderImpl.build(Crc32MismatchException.java:88)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.validateChecksum(Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.java:62)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.close(Crc32ChecksumValidatingInputStream.java:50)\n\tat java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:179)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.FunctionalUtils.lambda$safeRunnable$5(FunctionalUtils.java:124)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.FunctionalUtils.invokeSafely(FunctionalUtils.java:140)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.lambda$handle$2(JsonResponseHandler.java:87)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:87)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonResponseHandler.handle(AwsJsonResponseHandler.java:43)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.lambda$handle$0(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDurationUnsafe(MetricUtils.java:63)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.handle(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:95)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$resultTransformationResponseHandler$8(BaseClientHandler.java:262)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleSuccessResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:99)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:75)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:60)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:41)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClient.query(DefaultDynamoDbClient.java:4046)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.paginators.QueryIterable$QueryResponseFetcher.nextPage(QueryIterable.java:134)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.paginators.QueryIterable$QueryResponseFetcher.nextPage(QueryIterable.java:125)\n\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.PaginatedResponsesIterator.next(PaginatedResponsesIterator.java:58)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:693)\n\tat

**AWS Java SDK version used and Java Version used**

2.17.27

java 17

**Snipped code:**

```
 AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(getAccessKey(), getSecretKey());

 DynamoDbClient.builder()
    .region(Region.of(getRegion()))                    
    .endpointOverride(URI.create(getEndpoint()))                    
    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
    .build();
```

**Related same issue but we are unable to find the solution:**

[Getting Crc32MismatchException when using dynamodb enhanced client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176090/getting-crc32mismatchexception-when-using-dynamodb-enhanced-client)

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3703

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0/software/amazon/awssdk/core/exception/Crc32MismatchException.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution

```
DynamoDbClient.builder()  
    .region(Region.of(getRegion()))  
    .endpointOverride(URI.create(getEndpoint()))  
    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
    .overrideConfiguration(o -> o.putHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")).build();
```

Comment: "Possible"? Does it work? What changed?

Comment: .overrideConfiguration(o -> o.putHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"))

It is not working